# Vue bind to dynamic slot element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I want to pass the component a button in a slot, which will have an action. For example a table, which have an "add row" functionality.

```
<my-table :data="data" :cols="cols"> 
   <button slot="add_row"></button>
</my-table>
```

Or, this disassembled alert:

```
<alert>
   <button slot="close">Remove the alert</button>
</alert>
```

which have the following template:

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
   <slot></slot>
</div>
```

The thing is, I want inside the component definition, to bind an event action to the `<slot>`ed button, but still letting the component user to provide his own button (or sometimes even a link, `<a>` element).

I've considered using a directive for the action buttons, similar to this library:
https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal
where the modal button has a `v-b-modal` directive. But couldn't find out how to do that.

**UPDATE:**
I'm trying to implement this using a directive. This is what I have so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/uvd6knLh/

```
Vue.component('alert', {
    template: `
  <div class="alert alert-info" v-if="show">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>`,

  data() {
        return {
    show: true
    }
  },
  mounted() {
     // directive event
     this.$root.$on("alert:close", () => this.show = false);
  }
});

Vue.directive('alert-dismiss', {
   inserted: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    el.addEventListener("click", () => {
        vnode.context.$root.$emit("alert:close");
    });
   }
});
```

So I listen for the directive event. The problem is that the directive event will cause all the alerts components to close, as you can see in the jsfiddle.
How to make this pattern work?

Comment: Here is an example using scoped slots. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/GGWKPE?editors=1010

Comment: Also [here is the source](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/src/directives/modal/modal.js) for the `v-b-modal` directive if you wanted to take that approach.

Comment: I'm trying to go with the directive, but couldn't figure out how the directive communicates with the component

Comment: What they are doing is emitting an event from the $root when the element with the directive is clicked and listening for that event in the modal component.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to implement this pattern - using directives, but that does not work properly, see my update. How to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

To provide data and actions from a child element (`<my-table>`) to it's parent, you can have a look [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots).

Scoped slots works really well when the child has some internal state that is not relevant to the parent, or to provide custom attribute or callbacks to a child and leave the markup and styling to the parent component.

However in your case, since it's the parent that holds the **data** attribute, I am not sure that it's the best solution. The child should not mutate it.

You could simply resolves the events on the parent component.

Comment: I'd rather put the visibility of the alert on the parent, otherwise the alert would always need to be set to visible when it's mounted instead of being controlled by the parent component.

Comment: From the comments, I see that scoped slots does solve the problem.. I can pass a custom button and set its handler in the parent myself. But I actually don't like the syntax, it's not clear enough. I prefer to go with the directive way. I can't find how to communicate between an inner directive and the component

Comment: directives have changed in the latest releases, and are not linked to a component instance anymore but only to a DOM node (make them very useful for integrating js libraries). If you really want to go the directive way, it will be hacky, you can persist state on the DOM node directly.

Comment: Can you give an example, what do you mean by persist state on the DOM node? Or any way how to provide action directives for a component, as I see this implemented in some vue components. The slot-scope way of "exporting" the handler function just seems not very intuitive to me

Comment: I also consider event delegation (checking the event.target), if the directive will be too hacky. but I prefer binding click events directly